# How can I round down DateTime but 23 times?

Tags: c#, datetime

```
for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++)
{
    var dt = RoundDown(DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
    datestimes.Add(dt);
}
```

And

```
DateTime RoundDown(DateTime date, TimeSpan interval)
{
    return new DateTime(
        (long)Math.Floor(date.Ticks / (double)interval.Ticks) * interval.Ticks
    );
}
```

datestimes is `List<DateTime>`

I need to make that the first time to be rounded will be the current DateTime.Now for example if it's 23:44 then round it down to 23:40 and this is what happens now.

But from this point I want to round down more 22 times for example 23:40, 23:35, 23:30, 23:25 like that more 22 times and to add each time the rounded date time to the List

Comment: So what’s the issue with your code?

Comment: @viveknuna it's adding to the list the same datetime it's rounding the same current date time and not rounding down each time more 5.  The list should be 14:35 , 14:30 , 14:25...but the list now is 14:35 , 14:35 , 14:35....it's rounding down only once the same date time 23 times.

Comment: `var dt = DateTime.Now;` above the `for` loop. Then `dt = RoundDown(dt, ...);` in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only do the round down once. Then, subtract the interval instead of rounding.

```
DateTime dt = RoundDown(DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

while ( dt.Minutes != 0 )
{
    // your code
    dt = dt.AddMinutes(-5);
}
```

Comment: While I doubt the capitalisation in `dt.minutes` (and in `once, Then`), this changes the loop in an unwarranted way.

Comment: @greybeard - the capitalisation in the `Minutes` property was wrong, as it was in the `while` keyword. I've fixed both with an "improve edit" on [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30082022) that you rejected. You state that "the first assignment assigns a Double to a DateTime" - which isn't true - the [`DateTime.AddMinutes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addminutes) method returns a `DateTime`. Attempting to assign a `double` to a `DateTime` would, as you point out, not work.

Comment: I just did a quick pseudo code, didn't really check that it compiled or anything, I was just trying to show the concept :)

Answer (score 1):

Declare the `DateTime.Now` variable before the loop. Get the minutes and get the rounded value. And then run a for loop and keep on decreasing the minutes by 5 and add to your list.

To get the largest number smaller than or equal to a number N and divided by K you can write the simple method.

```
int findNum(int N, int K)
{
    int rem = N % K;
 
    if (rem == 0)
        return N;
    else
        return N - rem;
}
```

In your case `K` is 5.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to actually **decrease** the date value that is being rounded down, which can be done with `.AddMinutes(-5 * i)`.

Besides that, it's also more efficient to calculate the date only once. Doing so then also prevents race conditions in case your code runs while the clock changes behind the scenes to the next 5-minute interval.

Improved code:

```
var startDate = DateTime.Now;
for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++)
{
    var dt = RoundDown(startDate.AddMinutes(-5 * i), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
}
```

Working demo: *https://dotnetfiddle.net/6o5HyW*